# problem with drawing line(directions) on Map?

Tags: android

In my map i used to given route,from and to directions in CAR mode but the lines in curving place are breaking.I want to give smooth lines without breaking.Please give me guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we want to get smooth lines the use below lines in ur code

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

I used above lines to get smooth direction route.